# IBKR Trading Commissions for US stocks

Tags: brokerage, online-trading, interactive-brokers

I have a question regarding the commission for US stocks for IBKR pro (tiered and fixed).

My first question is, what is the difference between tiered and fixed and how do you choose between the two when trading? Can you choose ?

This is the table with commissions that I found:

[image]

Assuming that I choose to use IBKR Pro - Fixed (also assuming that I can make a choice), do I have to pay 0.005 per share per transaction ? If I make a transaction to buy 2 shares of something, do I have to pay 0.01 USD?

**The second question is**, what is **minimum per order** and what is **maximum per order** ? Do I have to pay 1 USD per order if I choose IBKR Pro-Fixed ? What do they mean by minimum and maximum per order exactly ? Does it have anything to do with the commission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do they mean by minimum and maximum per order exactly ?

Minimum commission and maximum commission for any single order.

> Assuming that I choose to use IBKR Pro - Fixed (also assuming that I can make a choice), do I have to pay 0.005 per share per transaction ? If I make a transaction to buy 2 shares of something, do I have to pay 0.01 USD?

No, you'd pay a minimum of $1 per transaction. So you'd have to trade more than 2,000 shares to get above the minimum.

From what I can tell you select the fee schedule when you set up the account, not per trade. You can change it, but it does not take effect immediately.

> how do you choose between the two when trading?

Run some numbers on how many trades and shares you plan to trade and see which one gives you the best deal. Note that all plans have additional regulatory fees that may vary, but should be significantly less than the commissions.

Comment: what do you mean by 'So you'd have to trade 200 shares to reach the minimum.'. Also, then, what is the 0.005 USD in the IBKR Fixed ? Assuming that I'm using IBKR Fixed and I buy 100 shares of a stock trading at 5 dollars, how much do I have to pay in commission ?

Comment: Sorry, 2,000: 2,000 shares * 0.005 = $1. What I mean by that was you'd have to trade more than that to get _above_ the minimum

Comment: "Assuming that I'm using IBKR Fixed and I buy 100 shares of a stock trading at 5 dollars, how much do I have to pay in commission ?" $1 (the minimum)